# Multilingual Word: switching between languages for menus, dialogs, &c

Tags: microsoft-word, multilingual

When working by myself, I work in English, but when working through issues with clients, most of whom are not native-English speakers, I would prefer to be able to "flip" to their language, so that I can explain exactly what they should do in terms of what they see on their machine.

Is that kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Microsoft Office 2010 you can download [Office ScreenTip Language pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/)

For earlier versions you can use [Language Interface Packs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/office-language-interface-pack-lip-downloads-HA001113350.aspx)

Comment: For language packs: "With Office Language Packs, customers can easily switch the display and dialog boxes of Microsoft Office programs between different languages." - Well, that was easy!  But at €27 per language for  9 languages, that gets out of the realm of cheap.  And Office 2010's interface is so different from the predecessor's, so I might need at least one language for previous versions.  But I guess this is the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you Try [lingoes](http://www.lingoes.net/) Its a free tool that is Making my Life much easier!

> Lingoes is an easy and intuitive dictionary and text translation software, It offers lookup dictionaries, full text translation, capture word on screen, translate selected text and pronunciation of words in over 80 languages. These language are English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, Russian, Greek, Swedish, Turkish, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Arabic, Hebrew, Vietnamese, Thai and more...

Comment: How would this help me?  I am able to talk with my clients, it is a matter of having us both usethe same names for menus, &c.